# JDBC: complains about invalid sign but seems fine

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, ora-00911

I have to use JDBC to write to a database (hibernate/ibatis is not an option) and my database is Oracle 11g.

I create the following query: `insert into user(user_id, username, age, creation_ts) values(seq_userid.NEXTVAL, 'Jack', 19,TO_TIMESTAMP('14/12/2010 15/09/46', 'DD/MM/RR HH24/MI/SS'));`

However my `statetement.execeuteUpdate(above sql)`. generates an invalid sign exception.
But when I perform the query in squirrel it gets commited just fine.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

---

```
Edit:
user table:
id: number : not null
username varchar2(30) not null
age number(10) not null
creation_ts timestamp not null

Error:
ORA-00911: invalid character

Java snippet:
try
        {       
            DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
            String url = "privatized";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();

            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormatString);
            String formattedDate = formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault()).getTime()); 

            StringBuilder insertQuery = new StringBuilder("insert into user(user_id, username, age, creation_ts) values(seq_userid.NEXTVAL,");
                insertQuery.append(username);
                insertQuery.append(",");
            insertQuery.append(age);
            insertQuery.append(",TO_TIMESTAMP('");
            insertQuery.append(formattedDate);
            insertQuery.append("', 'DD/MM/RR HH24/MI/SS'));");
            System.err.println(insertQuery.toString());
            st.executeUpdate(insertQuery.toString());

            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex){
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.err.println(ex.getCause().toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("=========================================");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the spec of the table in question. The Java code excerpt could be helpful, too.

Comment: Does it have an oracle exception?

Comment: What is an Invalid Sign Exception?  Could you paste the error / stack trace?

Comment: Try removing the semicolon from the end of your query

Comment: From google search for ORA-00911 http://techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00911.php  How are you building your statement?  Action 3 on the page may be your issue.

Comment: Maybe 2010 is YYYY? How are you formatting the date?

Comment: dwb the java code is shown in my latest edit. pouncep: private static final String dateTimeFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy HH/mm/ss";  I'll give it a try, but it would surprise me a bit since squirrel accepts the query just fine. I'd except it to cut the 20 part off.

Comment: Just tried it and changed the timestamp format from RR to RRRR didn't solve anything. I think it has to do with the jdbc part since the copied output works just fine in squirrel/sqldeveloper.

Comment: have you tried running your statement manually in sqlplus?

Comment: Yes, that's why I was so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I put in a comment above, the issue could be due to the extra Semicolon at the end of your SQL statement. see this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/58a27505-a3fb-4cb1-9063-3946b3f26acd)

You may also want to look at [PreparedStatments](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to make your life easier. Here would be a rough translation of your above code. I have left some parts, and there are most likely errors.

```
String query = "insert into user(user_id, username, age, creation_ts) values(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
... //fill in all your parameters
pstmt.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) );
... //execute here
```

Comment: Sigh, indeed the same error as that user. Hours of debugging over something so stupid. And I didn't read anything about that in the documentation... Sometimes good habbits turn out badly...

Comment: I went through the same thing 2 months ago, and found that link then. Easy mistake to make.

Comment: And thank you for the setTimeStamp hint. That does indeed shave quite a few lines of the code and improves the readability by quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('14/12/2010 15/09/46', 'DD/MM/RR HH24/MI/SS')
```

You send a 4-digit year but the format string defines a 2-digit year (no century)

Give this a try:

```
insertQuery.append("', 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24/MI/SS'));");
```

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't solve it, thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the value of the `username` variable is `'Jack'` and not `Jack`? (the ORA-00911 error doesn't look like a typical date format error).

Also you should learn about [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). They are more efficient, easier to read and debug and not susceptible to SQL injection.

My java is a bit rusty, but this would look something like this with a `PreparedStatement`:

```
String query = "insert into user(user_id, username, age, creation_ts) values "
              + "(seq_userid.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?)";

Statement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);

st.setString(1, username);
st.setInt(2, age);
st.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(
                          Calendar.getInstance(
                             TimeZone.getDefault()).getTimeMillis()));

st.executeUpdate(insertQuery.toString());
```

This way you don't need to convert a date to a string to get it converted back by the DB. Also you may find the statement easier to read and you will never have to worry about user's naming their account [with a ' (single-quote)](http://xkcd.com/327/) :)

Comment: Hello Vincent, I'm certain it resolves to jack. I printed the sql statement and that's what I got as result. And I'll give the PreparedStatements a look. In all honesty I don't often use JDBC. I'm more familiar with hibernate/Ibates where I can just set the values.

Comment: @jack: as [Sean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440022/jdbc-complains-about-invalid-sign-but-seems-fine/4440482#4440482) pointed out this doesn't look like a date format error. PreparedStatement are definetely the way to go, I hope you'll have a look :) (I've updated my answer with an example)

Comment: I certainly will. In all honesty I'd forgotten about them. Too much hibernate.